# PullRefresh plugin of a List doesn't handle ChainedStore possibility

Tags: extjs, extjs-stores, extjs7

Using Ext JS 7.1 Modern, I have prepared an example to show the problem.

When I have remote filters on my main store, binding the `dataview.List` to a `ChainedStore` correctly handles my local filtering. However, when I also add a `PullRefresh` plugin to the list, I get an error during pull refresh. I see from the source code that the plugin doesn't consider the possibility that a list's store can be a `ChainedStore`.

I have tried to explain the problem with a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/330m) and also attached the code below.

I have temporarily solved the problem by overriding the `fetchLatest` and `onLatestFetched` methods of `Ext.dataview.pullrefresh.PullRefresh` plugin, to use the `source` store if the list's store is a `ChainedStore`. But I believe the source code must be updated to handle this case.

app.js

```
Ext.define('App.model.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName']
});

Ext.define('App.store.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.teststore',

    model: 'App.model.Test'
});

Ext.define('App.viewmodel.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.test',
    data: {
        query: ''
    },
    stores: {
        test: {
            type: 'teststore',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'names.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            },

            remoteFilter: true,
            filters: {
                property: 'id',
                value: 1
            }
        },
        chained: {
            type: 'chained',

            autoLoad: true,
            source: '{test}'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('App.controller.TestController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.testcontroller',

    doSearch: function (field) {
        var list = this.lookup('list'),
            store = list.getStore(),
            value = field.getValue();

        if (Ext.isEmpty(value)) {
            store.removeFilter('firstName')
        } else {
            store.filter([{
                property: 'firstName',
                value: value,
                operator: 'like'
            }])
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('App.dataview.TestList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'testlist',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'test'
    },

    plugins: [{
        type: 'pullrefresh',
        mergeData: false
    }],

    emptyText: 'Name not found',
    bind: {
        store: '{chained}'
    },
    itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{id} <b>{firstName} {lastName}</b></div>'
});

Ext.define('App.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    controller: 'testcontroller',
    fullscreen: true,

    viewModel: {
        type: 'test'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'searchfield',
        ui: 'solo',
        placeholder: 'Search names',
        listeners: {
            buffer: 500,
            change: 'doSearch'
        },
        bind: {
            value: '{query}'
        }
    }, {
        reference: 'list',
        xtype: 'testlist'
    }]

})

Ext.application({
    name: 'App',

    mainView: 'App.MainView'
});
```

names.json

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Peter',
    lastName: 'Venkman'
}, {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Raymond',
    lastName: 'Stantz'
}, {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Egon',
    lastName: 'Spengler'
}, {
    id: 4,
    firstName: 'Winston',
    lastName: 'Zeddemore'
}]

var results = data.filter(function(record) {
    if (params.filter) {
        return record.id > params.filter[0].value
    }
})

return {
    "success": true,
    "data": results
}
```

App.override.dataview.pullrefresh.PullRefresh:

```
Ext.define('App.override.dataview.pullrefresh.PullRefresh', {
  override: 'Ext.dataview.pullrefresh.PullRefresh',

  privates: {
    fetchLatest: function() {
      const store = this.getStore().isChainedStore ? this.getStore().getSource() : this.getStore()
      store.fetch({
          page: 1,
          start: 0,
          callback: this.onLatestFetched,
          scope: this
      });
    },

    onLatestFetched: function(newRecords, operation, success) {
      var me = this,
          list = me.getList(),
          store = list.getStore().isChainedStore ? list.getStore().getSource() : list.getStore(),
          length, toInsert,
          oldRecords, newRecord, oldRecord, i;

      if (success) {
          if (me.getMergeData()) {
              oldRecords = store.getData();
              toInsert = [];
              length = newRecords.length;

              for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                  newRecord = newRecords[i];
                  oldRecord = oldRecords.getByKey(newRecord.getId());

                  if (oldRecord) {
                      oldRecord.set(newRecord.getData());
                  }
                  else {
                      toInsert.push(newRecord);
                  }
              }

              store.insert(0, toInsert);
          }
          else {
              store.loadRecords(newRecords);
          }

          me.setLastUpdated(new Date());
      }

      me.setState('loaded');
      list.fireEvent('latestfetched', me, toInsert || newRecords);

      if (me.getAutoSnapBack()) {
          me.snapBack(true);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Sorry, @Evan :) I just wanted to point out the problem and suggest that the source code should handle the ChainedStore possibility instead of us overwriting it since it might be considered as a bug.

With the Sencha support forum switching to Stack Overflow, I am not sure whether this is the right place to report these kinds of issues or not. Did I have to post this to [Ext JS 7.x Community Forums\Ext JS 7.x Bugs](https://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?173-Ext-JS-7-x-Bugs)?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that, but SO isn't really appropriate for bug reporting. Perhaps you could get in contact with Sencha and see what they say? AFAIK the 7.x bug forums is still accepting posts (for now).

Comment: Thanks @Evan, I will be posting this to 7.x Bugs. And in the future, I will not post possible bug reports here, unless I have a question and need a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this post, instead of being a question, was a bug report with a possible solution, it has been posted to Ext [JS 7.x Community Forums\Ext JS 7.x Bugs](https://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?173-Ext-JS-7-x-Bugs).

The above solution, that overwrites the plugin where source store is needed, works if anyone comes across the same issue.